# How to detect if a file has been renamed?

Tags: java, file, detection, file-rename

I am currently implementing **my own version of WatchService API** in *Java*.

(You can refer to this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-file-system-changes)  to understand what file *WatchService* does.)

I have **implemented code for** the following cases :

- Whenever a **file has been created** inside the directory or its sub-directory.
- Whenever a **file has been deleted** from the directory or its sub-directory.
- Whenever a **file has been modified** inside the directory or its sub-directory. *(based on the comparison of the last-modified date of files)*

I am facing a problem, whenever a file has been renamed, I don't understand how to track it.

This link contains the gist of my code at high level: [click here](https://paste2.org/wMAnIbkA)

Whenever a file has been renamed, I get 2 results

> **FILE DELETED :** *{old filename}*
>   **FILE ADDED :** *{new filename}*

But what I want the actual result to be is :

> **FILE RENAMED:** FROM *{old filename}* TO *{new filename}*

How do I tackle this challenge ?

I have provided a psuedo-code (which I think is enough to understand the problem at hand), If required I can provide the whole code too :)

Comment: How do you store this files? Do you have your own implementation of File class ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski Yes, I have my own File Class which stores various data, including creation date and last-modified date when the file was traversed by my code.

Comment: Since your particular watch-service would be running within its own thread I should think that you would need to maintain a files index. The index would need to be compared to whenever an event is fired. If the same number of files exist but one name is different yet it contains the same timestamp and checksum of a name that no longer exists then the file was renamed.

Comment: So you can store your actual File Name and if you want to change it then update variable with Old Name in your own File class then you can simply get this name if your if statement return that file was changed

Answer (score 0):

You can store hash for each file. 
When you detect that some files are deleted and some added compare hashes and if they match you found renamed/moved file.

Comment: Hashes can change when the content is modified.

Comment: @talex Can you elaborate, on what basis should this hash be calculated? I couldn't get your idea totally. Because if File is renamed/modified/moved, I guess the hashes may change for the same file.

Comment: @HariKrishna You have to update hash every time content is changed. It will be sloooow.

Comment: @MihirMehta hash of content. when file is renamed content remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a file is renamed, watcher service generate delete + create events. You should some how merge these two events as rename event.

You can create a unique id and assign it to the file. Refer this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/10/set-unique-identifier-to-file-in-java.html). Whenever you see a create event on a file and it has already some id, that mean it is renamed, else it is new creation. For newly created files, you should set the random unique id to keep track rename events.

Answer (score 0):

[JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net) supports `JNotify.FILE_RENAMED` event. As far as I understand this is a wrapper over native [inotify API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and it can catch file renaming at system level (changing name without changing file descriptor).